# During a SNCF strike, how can I check what trains will run without going to the station?

Tags: trains, france, high-speed-rail, delays, sncf

It seems there's currently a national SNCF strike on at the moment, and I'm trying to work out if it'll affect my journey later.

The people I booked my TGV tickets with advised me to check [infolignes.com](http://www.infolignes.com) for details of what's running and what isn't. When I go there, and pick my region, all I get is:

> TRAFIC TGV :
>
> 1 TGV sur 2 en moyenne.

If my train is one of the half running, then I can just turn up to the station and board as normal, all good! However, if it has been cancelled, I need to get to the station a long time in advance to get my ticket changed onto the previous service.

Without heading all the way to the station, is there any way to see which TGV services are actually running during a strike, and which ones aren't?

Comment: What about the “numéro de train” box on the homepage? It seems to provide train-by-train information, e.g. [here is a train that's been cancelled](http://www.infolignes.com/recherche.php?date_num_train=2014%7C06%7C13&num_train=7058) and [here is one running in part](http://www.infolignes.com/recherche.php?date_num_train=2014%7C06%7C13&num_train=7254)

Comment: Oh, ah, yes. Not sure how I missed that one...

Comment: In the small paper timetables it's actually written, but I don't know if this information is available online.

Comment: @pnut Yes, it's just that it was already mentioned in the question so I was afraid that I missed something. Maybe the best would be for Gagravarr to edit the link out of his question and write an answer himself.

Comment: @gerrit Which information?

Comment: @pnuts Why not? The website does not look like it was hastily put together and the URL seems to be in use since 2005. I never heard about it before but I think it's intended to be stable.

Comment: @pnuts [Here is info about a strike in 2010](https://web.archive.org/web/20101010113431/http://www.infolignes.com/).

Comment: @Relaxed I've seen printed timetables which had information indicated what trains would be cancelled during strikes, and what trains would continue to run.

Comment: @pnuts I must admit you lost me somewhere…

Comment: Note that if your train has been canceled due to a strike, [you can use it without any prior formality on any train the day before, the same day or the day after](http://www.sncf.com/fr/greve-questions-pratiques). Which isn't to say that turning up early at the station is a good idea, but you don't need to exchange your ticket. You can also get a full refund if you choose not to travel. This holds for all ticket types, even ones that do not otherwise allow modifications or cancellation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Promoting [Relaxed](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/6669/relaxed)'s comment to an answer... It's also on [infolignes.com/](http://www.infolignes.com/)!

[image: Screenshot]

If you do as I did, and select your region from the area I've labelled as #2, it will tell you about the general pattern for trains in your region. This is what tells you roughly how many trains will run on each line on a given day in the strike

Alternately, if you look at the large purple/pink box I've labelled #1, assuming you don't somehow miss it as I first did… You'll find the interface to look up the details for a given train, or a given route. Type in the details of the service(s) you want, and if it comes up with `À l'heure`, it's all good! `Service pertubé` means “irregular operations” and you should check if and when the train calls at your start and stop stations. `Arrêt ajouté` means “extra stop”, because another train going to this station has been cancelled.  Finally, `Arrêt supprimé` means you're out of luck, and need to head to the station to get re-booked onto another service.

As an example, assuming no changes between now and midday tomorrow, in the screenshot below the people going to Paris (5th in the list) or Boulogne (7th)
 are out of luck, Rue (4th) are lucky as there's an additional service, and the remaining the remaining 6 trains are (currently) running to time

[image: Live Departures]

Comment: “Arrêt ajouté” should be OK too, it means it's an extra stop (presumably to replace another train that was cancelled). “Arrêt supprimé” is what you don't want.

Comment: Ah, good to know. I've switched it for a different screenshot, is the new description now correct?

Comment: I think so yes (I already upvoted the answer).