# Delay due to strikes - can you claim on the SNCF Garantie Ponctualité?

Tags: trains, france, high-speed-rail, compensation, sncf

Thanks to [the question on checking SNCF trains during a strike](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/30381/26), I was able to discover that one of my trains today was cancelled. Sadly though, the only alternative involved a very hefty delay and an unexpected night in Paris...

Normally, one would be able to reclaim 75% of the cost of the ticket for a delay of 3 hours or more, under the [SNCF Garantie Ponctualité](http://www.voyages-sncf.com/guide/ponctualite). This would go some way towards the hotel costs, even if not really covering the inconvenience...

However, I'm not sure if that still applies if the cancellation was due to a strike. Are you able to claim under the [SNCF Garantie Ponctualité](http://www.voyages-sncf.com/guide/ponctualite) for delays caused by cancellations during a strike, or is that excluded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In practice, you're supposed to enter the details of your train on the site you linked to and you will see if you are entitled to any compensation (see the line “droit à une compensation”).

I just tried a train that was not running last week and the answer was “étude personnalisée”, which implies something like “on a case-by-case basis”. The reason for that is that the train was not late, it was cancelled… [and that's not the same for the SNCF](http://questions.sncf.com/questions/589290-panne-train-trajet-vichy-paris-train-indique-supprime-garantie-ponctualite-pb-etude-personnalisee) so that the *garantie* apparently does not apply.

Now, if you suffered a delay on the other train (compared to its schedule, not that of your original train), then you might still get something. But even if the train was actually late, the [flyer](http://medias.sncf.com/sncfcom/garantie-voyage/LA_GARANTIE_VOYAGE_Juillet_2013.pdf) also includes some warning about the SNCF reserving the right to “adapt” this program in “exceptional circumstances” so I wouldn't hold my breath.

Note that if you are stuck somewhere because of irregular operations, independently of any compensation for the delay, you can sometimes request a “bon de prise en charge pour un hôtel” at the station. I don't know if they hand those out during a strike but it's something to try (probably not possible afterwards, though).